# Nexus 5 with android 5.1 has battery life issue

Tags: charging, battery-life, nexus-5

I have `Nexus 5 with android 5.1`. The phone is fully discharged per day. Although I only make a few calls per day. How to fix it without downgrade to `adnroid 5`?

Comment: Rooted or not ?

Comment: @rjt.rockx, rooted.

Comment: Try underclocking your phone, because you only use it mainly for phone calls. Unless you are using memory-intensive battery-hungry monsters of an app, you don't need that much processing all the time. Use an app like PACPerformance to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Go to *Settings* > *Battery* and see which app or service is the culprit. Touch on the app that is using an unusual amount of battery and you can **FORCE STOP** or **REPORT** it from there.

Comment: I think, that there are wrong statistics in that menu. My `sms client` consume `25-50%`, but I don't send `SMS` at all.

Comment: @Denis - then the advice is doubly important. Use the hard press on the app to see if you are able to Force Close, or better yet, Disable it.

Comment: @wbogacz, yes, I can do Force Close, so Report. At present, I don't have Wi-Fi, so I don't send report yet.